# Help with basic Double Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

Given
$$
I = \int_t^T(X(t,s)\int_t^sX(t,u)du)ds, \;\;\text{how do I get }\;I = \frac{(\int_t^TX(t,u)du)^2}{2}.
$$

Many thanks for helping! And pardon me if this is straightforward.

Comment: Do you have more info on what is $X(t,u)$?

Comment: It is a deterministic function but the equality should be valid irrespective of its actual (deterministic) form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conveniently we always integrate over the second argument, and $t$ is the first's only value, and the only value of any integral's lower limit. Define $x(u):=X(t,\,u),\,y(u):=\int_t^u x(v)dv$ so $$I=\int_t^T y'(s)y(s)ds=\frac{y^2(T)-y^2(t)}{2}.$$By definition $y(t)=0$, while $y(T)=\int_t^T X(t,\,u) du$, completing the proof.

Comment: wow, looks easy now! Many thanks!